# Why only even integers occur in reflection indices of $\rm KCl$?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, diffraction, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

I was reading kittel and came across this .Its mentioned that since scattering factors of k+ and cl- are almost same the entire crystal appears to be a simple cubic crystal of constant $a/2$. but how this leads to the fact that only even integers appear as reflection indices for $\rm KCl$?

[image]

Comment: This might be better suited for [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Charlie - crystal structure and diffraction is certainly fair game on physics. Some might argue that it is less suited for Chemistry even. For the OP, calculate out what the diffraction from a simple cubic lattice with a/2 and compare...

Comment: @JonCuster Better suited was a poor choice of words, my bad, I only meant that there may be more people able to answer in that SE.

Comment: @Charlie I agree with Jon Custer, this is textbook solid state physics and is perfectly placed here. I would answer if my knowledge wasn't so wishy washy on this matter, as this was years and years ago for me.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't know much about solid state physics but x-ray crystallography was something covered in chemistry undergraduate so I only made the connection that way.